# Why's my code firing inconsistently using onDoubleClick to send the server data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I cannot figure out for the life of me why the first pair of `onDoubleClick` fires `500` server error but on all subsequent `onDoubleClick`s, it fires `200` correctly but with inconsistent behavior depicted below.

For illustration purposes, this is what's happening:

1. *double click* on image A for user ID `1` -> 500 error
2. *double click* on image A for user ID `1` -> 200 success (updates successfully for user ID `1`)
3. *double click* on image B for user ID `2` -> 200 success (updates successfully for user ID `1` when it should've been updated for user ID `2`)
4. and so on....

I've checked all over SO, even tried all of the suggestions on the most popular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) asked on this topic on SO but to no avail.  I've hit a brick wall.

I believe it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of hooks and how I'm defining them but I'm not entirely sure.

How can I make it so that upon double clicking any image, the corresponding data gets sent to the server correctly on the first pair of double clicks as well as any subsequent pair double clicks (i.e. on a different image)?

For illustration purposes, this how I'd like it to behave:

1. *double click* on image A for user ID `1` -> 200 success (updates successfully for user ID `1`)
2. double click* on image b for user ID `2` -> 200 success (updates successfully for user ID `2`)
3. and so on....

```
const Images = () => {
  let authToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

  const [uploadsData, setUploadsData] = useState([]);
  const [likedPhotoUserId, setLikedPhotoUsedId] = useState("");
  const [like, setLike] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUploads();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {}, [uploadsData]);

  const getUploads = () => {
    const headers = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    };

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8005/api/get-user-uploads-data", { headers })
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data);
        setUploadsData(resp.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (e) => {
    setLikedPhotoUsedId(e);
    sendUserLikePost();
  };

  const sendUserLikePost = () => {
    const url = "http://localhost:8005/api/post-user-like";

    const headers = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    };

    let data = {
      like: like,
      UserID: likedPhotoUserId,
    };

    console.log(data);

    axios
      .post(url, data, { headers })
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const displayUploadsData = () => {
    return uploadsData.map((photos, index) => {
      return (
        <ImagesGrid
          src={photos.url}
          likes={photos.likes}
          userName={photos.name}
          key={index}
          doubleClick={handleLikesBasedOnUserId}
          value={photos.UserID}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  return <>{displayUploadsData()}</>;
};

const ImagesGrid = (props) => {
  const createUserPhotoNodes = () => {
    return (
      <section className="gallery">
        <div className="container">
          <form method="POST" name="likes">
            <div className="img-container">
              <img
                src={props.src}
                alt="Photo"
                className="gallery-img"
                onDoubleClick={() => props.doubleClick(props.value)}
              />
              <h2 className="userName">{props.userName}</h2>
              <h2 className="likes" onChange={props.onChange}>
                Likes {props.likes}
              </h2>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  };

  return <>{createUserPhotoNodes()}</>;
};
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the general consensus among web usability people is that double-click is a terrible idea, because almost everything people encounter on websites are single-click action elements (buttons etc).

Comment: @Pointy For what it's worth, this is clearly emulating Instagram's UX, where double-clicking/double-tapping an image is the like action.

Comment: @AKX yes that's correct, this is just a project I've created to see how that whole process works.

Comment: @AKX that may be true, however double-clicking is objectively problematic on the web because it is pretty rare, also browsers *also* fire the first click action, or at least they used to. Instagram is sort-of special in that it seems almost completely oriented towards touch devices (phones, mainly), not mouse-oriented "click" clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit the nail on the head – it's because `setState` is asynchronous and [you're seeing stale props or state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function) to boot.

With

```
const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (e) => {
    setLikedPhotoUsedId(e);
    sendUserLikePost();
};

const sendUserLikePost = () => {
    // ...
    let data = {
        'like': like,
        'UserID': likedPhotoUserId
    };
    // ...
```

`likedPhotoUserId` will not have updated before you call `sendUserLikePost`, so `likedPhotoUserId` is `''`. (By the time you call `handleLikes...` again it will have the "previous" value.)

I don't see a reason why `likedPhotoUserId` should be a state atom anyway, since all you use it for is `sendUserLikePost` – just make it a regular ol' parameter:

```
const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (e) => {
    sendUserLikePost(e);
};

const sendUserLikePost = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
    // ...
    let data = {
        'like': like,
        'UserID': likedPhotoUserId
    };
    // ...
```

Comment: wow of course... thanks so much man!